# How to use BaseClass

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have an piece of the code here like this.

```
 class TextBox
    {

        TextBox()
        {
            _guid = new Guid();
        }
        private Guid _guid;
        public Guid Guid {
            get { return _guid; }
            private  set { value = _guid; }

        }


        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
```

However I have also other items like Button class ,CheckBox class etc.How can avoid code repeating everytime implementing the Guid properties and generation.

Comment: Why do you need the GUID?

Comment: Make a class that has the Guid property and inherit that class?

Comment: You could study the WinForms Controls hierarchy and how inheritance is used. Obviously, though, if you are running in a GUI environment, you should be careful not to conflict with the existing objects using namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `baseclass` that will instantiate the `Guid` upon construction. Each control will just simply inherit from the base.

```
public class TextBox : Identifier
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class CheckBox : Identifier
{

}

protected class Identifier
{
    public Guid Guid 
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    protected Identifier()
    {
        Guid = new Guid();
    }
}
```

Though, if the purpose of the Guid is to have a unique identifier, I would recommend just getting the Hash of the instance.

Example:

```
var textBoxId = MyTextBox.GetHashCode();
```

Note: As mentioned by @Maarteen, GetHashCode does not guarantee uniqueness. Per docs:

> The default implementation of the GetHashCode method does not
>   guarantee unique return values for different objects. Furthermore, the
>   .NET Framework does not guarantee the default implementation of the
>   GetHashCode method, and the value it returns will be the same between
>   different versions of the .NET Framework. Consequently, the default
>   implementation of this method must not be used as a unique object
>   identifier for hashing purposes.

Comment: thank you answer.may be not appropriate to ask here but if u point me out I ll glad to.I wanna generate html code fom this class.there is some way to that messy way but how can I do that most approprite way.Thank you

Comment: are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: web base application.I just wanna generate html form.so that I create an class library,and include it mvc app.

Comment: Mind posting a separate question? there will be various ways to do this, and explanation will be too much for a comment.

Comment: The `.GetHashCode` method does **not** yield a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend an existing control, you have to inherit this control

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

You will have to repeat this for every control since you cannot change the existing controls. If you would create your inheritance hierarchy from scratch (which is not possible with controls), you would just add these properties in the base class and derive other classes from it.

If you want to integrate more complex functionality, you can use composition, i.e. create the new functionality separately and call it from derived classes

```
public class ComplexFunctionality
{
    private readonly Control _c;

    public ComplexFunctionality(Control c)
    {
        _c = c;
    }

    public void SettingGuid(Guid newGuid)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private readonly ComplexFunctionality _cs = new ComplexFunctionality(this);

    private Guid _guid;
    public Guid Guid {
        get { return _guid; }
        private  set { 
            _cs.SettingGuid(value);
            _guid = value;
        }
    }
}
```